# wcf duplex service freezes on callback call

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, servicehost

Service contract:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IClientCallBackChannel),
SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
 public interface IServerService
 {
     [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
      void foo();
 }
```

Client contract:

```
public interface IClientCallBackChannel
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    object DoCommand(Command command);
}


class ClientCallBackChannelImpl
{
    public object DoCommand(Command command)
    {
        // freezes service
        serverService.foo();

        // OK
        new Action(() =>
        {
             Thread.Sleep(1000);                          
             serverService.foo();                                          
        }
            ).BeginInvoke(null,null);

     }            
}
```

I have a duplex service and when I am calling a client method 'DoCommand' that inside that method there is a call to a Service method foo, my service freezes.
If I call foo asynchronously it works fine, but I need the call to be synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need the DoCommand to return a value and so are not able to make it OneWay. If you think about this, this has to block your Service.

You can set the [ConcurrencyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx) of your ServiceBehavior to Multiple and this should work but IMHO it's not the best option.

As you have a two-way communication try sticking to OneWay-Methods - this will solve the problem and prevent you from difficult concurency problems with the above mentioned behaviour.

Comment: I tried setting the ConcurrencyMode of my ServiceBehavior to Multiple but it still blocks.

Comment: both in your service and client? Strange - anyway, try refactoring into only OneWay-methods if you want to call one within the other.

Comment: and one more thing: I only see half your code - make sure that you don't call the DoCommand within foo again - maybe you got some endless-loop here...